# How to export images from Excel table

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-office, vba, microsoft-excel-2013

I have an Excel table with two columns: `id` and `picture`.
`id` is a string and `picture` contains a single jpeg picture.
This table contains almost 1,000 rows.

[image: data sample]

Is it possible to export the images as jpeg files to the hard disc using the `id` as file name?

Comment: Can you please give us an example of the data.

Comment: I have edited my post .

Comment: what have you tried to achieve it? You can find useful information here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18232987/export-pictures-from-excel-file-into-jpg-using-vba

Comment: And http://superuser.com/questions/624445/how-to-save-duplicate-images-in-excel-to-different-jpegs